# DataFrame with Index to Numpy Retaining Index

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Index   Value
    1   10
    7   2
    9   8
```

I am trying to input these values in an `np.zeros` array that has a length of 10. The values in the dataframe should be in the numpy array corresponding to their index:

```
array([0.,10,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,2,0.,8])
```

Whats the best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to the DataFrame's index, or to a column named "Index". If it's the latter, it's extremely misleading. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({"Index": [1,7,9], "Value": [10,2,8]})

x=np.zeros(10)

x[df["Index"]]=df["Value"]
```

Outputs:

```py
[ 0. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  8.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reindex` + `to_numpy`

---

```
df['Value'].reindex(range(10), fill_value=0).to_numpy()
```

```
array([ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  8], dtype=int64)
```